# Executing Batch Script for TFS in Jenkins

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, tfs, copy

I am trying to run automate a tf command in Jenkins dev in order to have a folder B in TFS being updated when a first folder A in TFS is changed, files are added..etc..; So, basically, B is like a copy of A. The whole thing happens in the DEV environment, and then I checkin the changes from Jenkins as well..But, for some reasonand it is not letting me do this , I get tf is an undefined error. I tried to write a Windows Batch command to run the tf commands, but not working.. The only cmd like tool that works is with tfpt.exe. So, I was trying to have Jenkins run the following batch script:

```
withEnv(["PATH=c:\tftp\parent\dir;${env.PATH}"]){ bat "tftp.exe  
tf merge $/ServerFolderA  $/ServerFolderB / recursive ' "}
```

and I do have the TFS plugin in Jenkins installed
but does not work...
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the full path of tf.cmd/tf.exe or add it to the system environment variable (System Properties > Advanced > Environment Variables> Edit Path system variable to add tf.cmd/tf.exe path at the end).